# why fs is the only I/O library to provide sync call in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

recently I am doing research on this question. I have read fs source code and found out the only difference between fs.readSync() and fs.read() is

```
// async vrsion
  var req = new FSReqWrap();
  req.oncomplete = cb;
  binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path), req);
```

I read some article said the diffenece between blocking and non-blocking fs api call is async version would run in the new v8 worker thread.

When I read this [article - daveeddy written](http://www.daveeddy.com/2013/03/26/synchronous-file-io-in-nodejs/) about fs system call performance on async vs sync. The conclusion is both async and sync call the same system call. However async run on worker thread and sync run on main thread.

My question is that I notice the comment below said

> Filesystem operations are one of the last in Node.js to be using blocking system calls (open, preadv, pwritev)

Where can I find out fs real system call ? Is this comment right or wrong?
This is the key point to answer my question "why fs is the only I/O library to provide sync call in NodeJS"

I am really curious about it. Thanks for your patience and further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is designed with servers in mind. Async calls doesn't reduce the amount of system call but allows you to utilize CPU better, by continuing calculations while I/O is in progress, or doing multiple I/O simultaneously.

Using the asynchronous version, the runtime will try to execute other jobs (callbacks) if queued (and thus multiplexing is possible). Using the synchronous version, it's easier to code since you get the result without using a callback.

Node's IO is wrapped by libuv and doing direct system calls is discouraged. You can do some sort of raw syscall using ffi, but probably C is the better tool for the job.

Comment: thanks for answer. I am just curious. :P  
My point is no matter how your api design , you want to handle io you must call system call. 
So I want to know no matter nodejs or libuv, what is the final system call on fs.